# How to change date format from DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?

Tags: c#

i need to change the format of my date string using C#

from : "06/16/2010"or "16/06/2010"

to : "2010-06-16"

can you please help me achieve this

thanks

Comment: _Please_ tell me you're not doing this for inclusion in an SQL string?  That's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @stakx - for a user with only 8 questions that's been here less than 2 months, there's not much wrong with it yet.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you already have it as a `DateTime`, use:

```
string x = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more details. You can specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to enforce the use of Western digits etc. This is more important if you're using MMM for the month *name* and similar things, but it wouldn't be a bad idea to make it explicit:

```
string x = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you have a string to start with, you'll need to parse it and then reformat... of course, that means you need to know the format of the original string.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do.

```
string datestring = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String dt = Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Now you got this for dt,
2010-09-09

Comment: That will display the *minutes* in the middle, rather than the *months*.

Comment: string dt=Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
i think now its display the month

Answer (score 0):

**We can do something like this**

```
DateTime date_temp_from = DateTime.Parse(from.Value); //from.value" is input by user (dd/MM/yyyy)
DateTime date_temp_to = DateTime.Parse(to.Value); //to.value" is input by user (dd/MM/yyyy)

string date_from = date_temp_from.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
string date_to = date_temp_to.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
```

*Thank you*

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps, particularly for a question that already has an accepted answer. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I appreciate your comment : David Buck