# How to convert date format to DD-MM-YYYY in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

How to convert date format to DD-MM-YYYY in C#? I am only looking for DD-MM-YYYY format not anything else.

Comment: Are you converting a string to another string?  Do you want to format a DateTime as a string with the `DD-MM-YYYY` format?  Which language: VB, C#, something else?  Please provide more info.

Comment: Be aware that the ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") formatting is case sensitive. If you use lower-case M's, you will not get month, something I have stumbled over too many times to count.

Comment: Please follow this link [DateTime Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074671/how-to-change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 54):

```
string formatted = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

will do it.

[Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) is a good reference for different formats.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but its not working..Below error i am getting..cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: How are you calling it? Doing exactly what i wrote will work. See MSDN for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: I am selecting Start Date and End date from the below query after that i am using for loop for all the selected value...Please have a look below. hrms_job = hrms_job.Append("SELECT [Job Code], [Job Name],[Start Date], [End Date] FROM [hrms_job$]");

Comment: for (int iRowCount = 0; iRowCount < hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iRowCount++) {JobCode = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["Job Code"].ToString();JobName = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["Job Name"].ToString();StartDate = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["Start Date"].ToString();
                    EndDate = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["End Date"].ToString();
                    JobCodeList.Add(JobCode + JobName);
                    
                } here only after For loop I want to format the start date and end date to DD-MM-YYYY format

Comment: @saurav2109 : You are confusing String and DateTime types. You must first parse your date in string into DateTime and then use ToString with formater to get desired result.

Comment: case matters... its 'yyyy' not 'YYYY'.

Answer (score 13):

According to one of the first Google search hits:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

```
// Where 'dt' is the DateTime object...
String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply but this is not working, string.format will not give us DD-MM-YYYY format, it will give DD/MM/YYYY format

Answer (score 12):

Here is the Simplest Method.

This is the String value: "5/13/2012"

```
DateTime _date;
string day = "";

_date = DateTime.Parse("5/13/2012");
day = _date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

It will output as: 13-May-2012

Answer (score 8):

```
string formattedDate = yourDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick responsecannot but its not working.. convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider' error I am getting

Answer (score 5):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply but this is not working, string.format will not give us DD-MM-YYYY format, it will give DD/MM/YYYY format

Comment: Works for me. Output is 10-01-2011

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime s1 = System.Convert.ToDateTime(textbox.Trim());
        DateTime date = (s1);
        String frmdt = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

will work

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

String.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

First convert your string into DateTime variable:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(your variable);
```

Then convert this variable back to string in correct format:

```
String dateInString = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: hrms_job = hrms_job.Append("SELECT [Job Code], [Job Name],[Start Date], [End Date] FROM [hrms_job$]");for (int iRowCount = 0; iRowCount < hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows.Count; iRowCount++){JobCode = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["Job Code"].ToString();JobName = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["Job Name"].ToString();StartDate = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["Start Date"].ToString();EndDate = hrms_jobdata.Tables[0].Rows[iRowCount]["End Date"].ToString();DateTime converteddate = DateTime.Parse(StartDate); string StartDateFormated = converteddate.ToString("DD-MM-YYYY");}

Comment: Below is my code, sorry for disturbing you again, but I am not geeting exactly what I want..After your suggestion now I am getting DD-02-YYYY, means i am getting month value but not all. Please help

Comment: Thhanks a lot Everyone..I got the solution..I was doing DD-MM-YYYY but actually it was dd-MM-yyyy that is case sensitive..Thanks a lot to all for all your nice support

Answer (score 1):

Here we go:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(time.Day + "-" + time.Month + "-" + time.Year);
```

WORKS! :)

Answer (score 1):

From C# 6.0 onwards (Visual Studio 2015 and newer), you can simply use an interpolated string with formatting:

```cs
var date = new DateTime(2017, 8, 3);
var formattedDate = $"{date:dd-MM-yyyy}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your date variable stored as a String or a Date type?

In which case you will need to do something like

`DateTime myDate = null;`

```
DateTime.TryParse(myString,myDate);
```

or

```
Convert.ToDateTime(myString);
```

You can then call ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") on your date variable

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  What I needed to do was add a reference at the top of the class and change the CultureInfo of the thread that is currently executing.

```
using System.Threading;

string cultureName = "fr-CA";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);

DateTime theDate = new DateTime(2015, 11, 06);
theDate.ToString("g");
Console.WriteLine(theDate);
```

All you have to do is change the culture name, for example:
    "en-US" = United States
    "fr-FR" = French-speaking France
    "fr-CA" = French-speaking Canada
    etc...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to convert a string, so first you should cast your variable to date and after that apply something like
`string date = variableConvertedToDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`
 or
`string date = variableConvertedToDate.ToShortDateString()` in this case result is dd/MM/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

```
dateString = "not a date";  
// Exception: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.  
DateTime dateTime11; // 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  
bool isSuccess2 = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime11);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked (even though it is asked poorly)

Answer (score -1):

```
var dateTimeString = "21‎-‎10‎-‎2014‎ ‎15‎:‎40‎:‎30";
dateTimeString = Regex.Replace(dateTimeString, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);

var inputFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss";
var outputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var output = dateTime.ToString(outputFormat);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Try this, it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

you could do like this:

```
return inObj == DBNull.Value ? "" : (Convert.ToDateTime(inObj)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").ToString();
```

Comment: Op asked for 'DD-MM-YYYY', not 'MM/dd/yyyy'