# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.
In my regional settings in cp , date format is set to dd.MM.yyyy .

I have in my gridview a column with type date.
In the gridview if I set a value to the cell in format dd.MM.yyyy

```
 `I get Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`.
```

But if I type a date in format MM.dd.yyyy it works , but I don't really understand why it happenes? and also If I set dd.MM.yyyy date format , manually in the table, it works.

The column is itemtemplate and the control of the column wasn't edited .

Answer (score 1):

mm refers to minutes MM refers to the day.
here is one reference on different formats available: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
myDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

refer here : [How to convert date format to DD-MM-YYYY in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649639/how-to-convert-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm not inserting something to format the date. I'm just updating the info from the gridview

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format of date into GridView.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="fieldname" HeaderText="Header text" ReadOnly="True"
                                                        SortExpression="fieldname" HtmlEncode="False" DataFormatString="{0:d}" / >
```