# Predefined Date Time class Properties are working on mm/dd/yyyy i want to show mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
DateTime dt=new DateTime(05/06/2014) this is in dd/mm/yyyy)
```

`dt.DayOfWeek` raturns value based on **mm/dd/yyyy** format its taking 5 as month 6 as date.  i want this has return a value based on **dd/mm/yyyy** format.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
`DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)` `Initializes` a new instance of the `DateTime` structure to the specified `year`, `month`, and `day`.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2014,6,5);
```

You can print the date in your specific format:

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);          // "05/06/2014"
String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt);          // "06/05/2014"
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

try using this:

```
DateTime dt=new DateTime(05/06/2014)
String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dt);
```

Correct overload for `DateTime` is

```
DateTime(int32 year, int32 month, int32 day)
```

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong Contructor, you have to use this Contructor:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(int year, int month, int day);
```

> DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)     Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to the specified year, month, and day.

See its detail [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcfzdy4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

you can see [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the list of all Contructors avaiable of `DateTime` class.

Answer (score 0):

Predefined datetime structure properties are working based on the Date and time format present in the Regional setting in your system. If you want to use a datetime for your application, you may refer this thread

[Set Default DateTime Format c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389187/set-default-datetime-format-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

In datetime function , you also give string format as you required like

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(yourObject.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string s = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");

or  

string s new datetime().ToString(give format here);
```

refer link
 [convert datetime to date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050102/convert-datetime-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

[How to convert date format to DD-MM-YYYY in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649639/how-to-convert-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c-sharp)