# How to remove time in my DataGridView column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

Hi I am creating a `GridView` data to show my CSV in the web application. I have a `gridview` from a data table with the `Goods Reciept` Date as `DateTime`. Question here is how to remove time from my Date of `Goods Reciept`.

```
public void Storage00B()
{
    DataTable StorType00B = new DataTable();
    StorType00B.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] {
        new DataColumn("Material", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Quantity", typeof(float)),
        new DataColumn("Date of Goods Reciept", typeof(DateTime)),
        new DataColumn("Date of Last transaction",typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Stock Status", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Storage Type", typeof(string))
    });
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
    int B = 0;
    int QB = 0;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (row.Field<String>(5) == "00B\r")
        {
            B++;
            if (row.Field<String>(4) == "Q")
            {
                QB++;
            }
        }
    }

    String StrTyp;



    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {

        StrTyp = dt.Rows[i][5].ToString();
        StorType00B.Rows.Add();
        if (StrTyp == "00B\r")
        {

            StorType00B.Rows[i][0] = dt.Rows[i][0];
            StorType00B.Rows[i][1] = dt.Rows[i][1];
            StorType00B.Rows[i][2] = dt.Rows[i][2];
            StorType00B.Rows[i][3] = dt.Rows[i][3];
            StorType00B.Rows[i][4] = dt.Rows[i][4];
            StorType00B.Rows[i][5] = dt.Rows[i][5];
        }
    }

    Stor_Type00B.Text = "Before IQA Stock Quantity :" + B;
    Q00B.Text = "Total Quality Stock :" + QB;
    StorType00B = StorType00B.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(row => !row.ItemArray.All(field => field is DBNull || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(field as string))).CopyToDataTable();
    DataView dv = StorType00B.DefaultView;
    dv.Sort = "Date of Goods Reciept ASC";
    StorageType00B.DataSource = dv;
    StorageType00B.DataBind();

}
```

Here is my current result

[image]

As you can see I want to remove the 12:00:00 AM because there's no time in my `Goods Reciept` date.

Comment: maybe it's possible to use a .ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") on the datetime value?

Comment: .ToShortDateString() is another option

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove time portion of date in C# in DateTime object only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121271/how-to-remove-time-portion-of-date-in-c-sharp-in-datetime-object-only)

Comment: Is that `StorageType00B` a GridView instance? Can you provide its markup to make sure the `DateFormatString` is properly set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [formatting your date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649639/how-to-convert-date-format-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c-sharp) into a string like `dd-MM-yyyy` format:

```
StorType00B.Rows[i][2] = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][2]).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

What about converting it to .NET `DateTime` and then use the [`Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_Date) property. Something like this:

```
StorType00B.Rows[i][2] = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i][2]).Date;
```