# Change Date Format and keep it as a date

Tags: c#

How to turn DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:0000 to YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:0000 and keep it as date format and not string in c#

i have tried many options but still did not find the right one.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074671/how-to-change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change date format from DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074671/how-to-change-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

(The tongue in cheek answer is) "You change the region in Windows"

You can't change the "format of a date"; DateTimes are represented internally as a number that bears no relation to the way humans divide time into years/months/days/hours/minutes etc. DateTimes have no format at all until they're turned into a string, just like "3", "3.0", "III" (Roman numerals) and "0x03" (hex) are all just formatted representations of the number 3. Any time you see a date on screen it has been turned into a string representation before being displayed to you. If you're looking at it in a debugger it will probably be deriving its appearance from the regional settings of your machine. If you're looking at it in a log and it wasn't written there with a specific format then it will be the format derived from the culture of the thread that wrote the log (which was probably derived from the windows region settings)

For more specific info , put a screenshot of where you're seeing this date

For now, keep your datetime as a datetime and don't worry how it appears unless the customer is demanding their PDF invoices has a date at the top in yyyy-MM-dd in which case you `invoicePdf.RenderString(invDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), new Point(0,0))` (for example)

**The bit about PDFs was an imaginary situation,** caused because you had provided no example or detailed code. I thought up a reasonable situation where there was a date (an invoice date) and someone demanding it has to be in *yyyy-MM-dd* (the customer). This is only a few words different from your actual situation where there is a date (your date) and someone (a web service) demanding it has to be in *yyyy-MM-dd*. You can then apply the advice given for the invoice scenario, to the web service scenario; they're both just `ToString(...)`

---

So you said "i'm calling a webservice that expects a date in yyyy-mm-dd" - it doesn't exactly make sense because there isn't a any such standard thing as "a webservice" and there are multiple different ways that things we think of as webservices can exchange data, so it's still not a huge amount of detail to go on. Being as vague as possible about your requirements make life really, really hard work for the people trying top help you. As a sofftware engineer you should operate at a much higher level of precision and detail when asking for help from other software engineers

Your webservice is either expecting a string that looks like a yyyy-MM-dd date, or its coded up so it looks like it's expecting a date, but the web server/runtime hosting the service will be doing the parsing of the string data that goes over the network.

If you're calling a webservice that is expecting a bunch of XML as its payload, then the WSDL should adequately describe the input parameter to the method such that when you add a service reference to it in VS< VS will generate you a client object that has a method that takes a C# datetime. Internally it will transform it to a string, and the other end will transform it back - you don't need to worry about it because it's not your problem

If your webservice is expecting JSON, it'll likely need a string formatted like a date as per ISO8601 though there isn't really a "standard" for JSON dates. Your JSON serializer will again take care of this for you if you're using one - you just bang an object into the serializer that contains a C# DateTIme and it will be converted to a string and back again at the other end

If you're accessing your service by serializing to string yourself because the webservice actually takes a string that looks like a date, then you'll need to serialize your date to a string manually using `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

---

I've said a few times that your spec is a bit vague; to sharpen it up, post the code of the method youre calling at the other end, or show us some JSON that makes the web service work and we'll tell you how to write C# that makes that JSON, or post a snippet of the WSDL, or even a screenshot of the swagger UI or a successful Postman call. You might even get some takers if all you did was post a link to the actual service method you're trying to call and asked for help on how to call specific method X particularly how to pass a date to it

Comment: @Aziz The webservice does not accept a datetime, it does accept a string that contains a date in a specific format. Your "_and_ _keep_ _it_ _as_ _date_ _format_ _and_ _not_ _string_" in the question is missleading

Comment: Then it's not going to be sent to the web service as a date, it will pass as a string. In this case you should format it using ToString as per my last paragraph. For more targeted help you will need to post the signature of the web service method you're calling (show us the WSDL or equivalent) but really, if you've added the web service as a reference and had VS build the client code for you then it's either demanding a "string that will be interpreted as a date" or it's demanding a date (and you supply a datetime - the web service client will format it for transmission over the network)

Comment: @Aziz, As this answer stated `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`, It will be a string.

Comment: @Aziz, This answer provides you with an example of how to use the method. On a variable `invDate` variable of type DateTime. Used in a method called `RenderString`, to be clear on the return type. You will notice that your question does not contain any code or examples. An example has been created to compensate for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime.ParseExact() method to specify the way you want a string representation of a date to be perceived. But like the previous answer by Caius said, there's no real format to worry about until you see a string representation of the date.